# how to combine jquery commands?

Tags: jquery

I have code like this

```
    $(document).on('click', '.addtocart .plus, .addtocart .minus', function () {
        var num = $('a.account span').text();
        .........
            .........
     });
```

Same code applies for

```
$(document).on('change','.addtocart .qty', function () {
        var num = $('a.account span').text();
        .........
            .........
 });
```

Can anyone tell me how to combine these `click` and `change` events?

Comment: Finally figure out it was the if/else?? check in your deleted question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution is to define a function

```
function f() {
     var num = $('a.account span').text();
     ...
}
$(document).on('click', '.addtocart .plus, .addtocart .minus', f)
.on('change','.addtocart .qty', f);
```

If you don't want to pollute the external namespace with this additional function, you may use an IIFE :

```
(function(){
  function f() {
     var num = $('a.account span').text();
     ...
  }
  $(document).on('click', '.addtocart .plus, .addtocart .minus', f)
  .on('change','.addtocart .qty', f);
})();
```